# Writing image into file- Wrong output

Tags: image, fwrite

I am trying to put an image into a file that has been retrieved from a server. I am using the `fwrite` function, but it doesn't really work the way I want it to. It looks like the biggest problem is that it can't write the `\` character. Or maybe not. I don't know what to do with it. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Here is my fwrite code:

```
FILE * pFile;
if((pFile = fopen ("test", "wb")) == NULL) error(1);
fwrite (buffer.c_str() , 1, buffer.size(), pFile);
```

where buffer contains data retrieved from server. When it contains pure html, it works just fine.

Here is my output:

```
GIF89a¥ÈÔ
```

Here is what it was supposed to write:

```
GIF89a\A5\C8\00
```

Comment: `buffer.size()` does not look like C code. If you use C++, use C++ coding style.

Comment: Yeah it is. I am writing it in C++, because of string functions.

Comment: Why are you trying to write binary data (the image file content) using `buffer.c_str()` (which is text)? The output you're getting now is much more like what the file should contain (if you display the binary data as text), while your desired output is not valid image file content.

Comment: And you used the C tag instead of the C++ tag to make things more interesting? I remove the C tag. Feel free to add the C++ tag **only**. And why not use iostreams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fwrite()` won't automatically do the conversion you want.
You should implement some code to convert what you want to convert to "`\` character".

example:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

void error(int no) {
    printf("error: %d\n", no);
    exit(1);
}

int main(void) {
    char data[] = "GIF89a\xA5\xC8"; // '\0' is automatially added after string literal
    std::string buffer(data, sizeof(data) / sizeof(*data));

    FILE * pFile;
    // use text mode because it seems you want to print text
    if((pFile = fopen ("test", "w")) == NULL) error(1);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++) {
        if (0x20 <= buffer[i] && buffer[i] <= 0x7E && buffer[i] != '\\') {
            // the data is printable ASCII character except for \
            putc(buffer[i], pFile);
        } else {
            // print "\ character"
            fprintf(pFile, "\\%02X", (unsigned char)buffer[i]);
        }
    }

    fclose(pFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've tried it. now my output looks like this: GIF89a\A5\01\C8\9A\D4\ , so the format is right but not all the values are.